# Server jar file missing (MCP 9.18)

Tags: java

I'm setting up a Client that can boost FPS on minecraft but whenever I try to decompile Mod Coder Pack (MCP) it throws out a error saying I'm missing a server jar file I have the jar file but I'm not sure where to put it.

I've tried to find some stuff that can help me on the internet but I can't find anything.

Heres the error

```
!! Missing server jar file. Aborting !!
```

After it shows that its missing the server jar file it will just recompile everything.

(I didn't really know what to put here.)

Edit: i found the problem if you're experiecing it then just check the answer that i made below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So i found out the problem if you're experiecing the same problem heres how to fix it

so go to

`https://mcversions.net/`

then download the version of what mcp you are using and then rename the

`server.jar`

to

`minecraft_server.jar`

then place it in the

`jars`

folder which is located where you extracted your MCP ZIP File this should fix everything.